# img preload not work in ie7, ie8

Tags: jquery

```
preload = function() {

        var imgList = [];
        var imgArr = [];
        var imageSize = element.find('img').size();
        var loadImgList = element.find('img');
        for(i=0; i<imageSize;i++){
            imgArr.push($(loadImgList[i]).attr('src'));
        }

        var total = imgArr.length;
        var loaded = 0;

        for(var i in imgArr) {
            imgList.push($("<img />")
                .attr("src", imgArr[i])
                .load(function() {
                    loaded++;
                    if(loaded == total) {
                        element.find('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
                        init();
                    }
                })
            );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this solves your problem since you're not saying what exactly doesn't work, but you need to set `src` *after* you define the handler for the `onload` event.

Also, note that `.load()` has numerous issues when used with images as outlined in the [jQuery docs:](http://api.jquery.com/load-event)

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the
>     same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's
>     cache

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for a no-javascript solution? Something like this:

```
<!-- Preload Images -->
<div style="display: none; width:1px; height:1px;">
<img src="1.png" />
<img src="2.png" />
<img src="3.png" /> 
</div>
```

Works very well for me. :)